# Exit before all attempts in Spring Retryable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-retry

I have written a Retryable in Spring boot. It will retry 5 times, and with a backoff of 5 seconds. I would also like to exit before 5 iterations, if some condition is met. It's like

```
    @Retryable(value = {SomeException.class}, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
    public void checkForProcessed() throws SomeException {
             if(someCondition) {
    //come out of the retryable before retrying for 5 times.

                }
    }
```

So let's say the condition is met in the third iteration, it should not retry for 2 more times, and should exit in the 3rd iteration itself

Comment: What is the problem here. it works in that fashion. It tries for 5 times. If it does not get an exception, it will exit with success.

Comment: @PythonLearner I want it to exit on some condition. If some condition is met, it should exit before trying further iterations

Comment: I would investigate implementing your own `RetryListenerSupport` components - it looks like there might be such possibility to implement such logic, however I've never done anything like this thus cannot advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw `SomeOtherException` (which is not retryable).